# Dynamic multiple forms: Change select options based on previous select value

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, vuejs2

I dynamically generate additional forms on a page using Django Model Formsets. The user can generate as many forms as they need. This is done in a Vuejs method.

My issue is changing the options of the second select of the form that the first select value was chosen. I was thinking about trying on focus or on click to get the select that was last changed, but I'm not sure how that would work.

I do track the current count of forms on the page.

In the example below. If the user changed form_select_0 to One, I need form_subselect_0 to only have options C and D, but the selects in form_1 should not be altered.

Example:

```
<form id = form_0>
    <select id="form_select_0">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <select id="form_subselect_0">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form id = form_0>
    <select id="form_select_1">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <select id="form_subselect_1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Follow-up:**
Added vue method (below) for how I'm currently adding Vuejs models to the Django Model Formsets. Question: Is there a better way?

```
addForm: function () {
    this.count++
    let form_count = this.count
    form_count++

    let formID = 'id_form-' + this.count
    incremented_form = this.vue_form.replace(/form-\d/g, 'form-' + this.count)
    this.formList.push(incremented_form)
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        let total_forms = document.getElementsByName('form-TOTAL_FORMS').forEach
        (function (ele, idx) {
            ele.value = form_count
        })
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above this was my final answer due to no response:

```
addForm: function () {
this.count++
let form_count = this.count
form_count++

let formID = 'id_form-' + this.count
incremented_form = this.vue_form.replace(/form-\d/g, 'form-' + this.count)
this.formList.push(incremented_form)
this.$nextTick(() => {
    let total_forms = document.getElementsByName('form-TOTAL_FORMS').forEach
    (function (ele, idx) {
        ele.value = form_count
    })
})},
```